# How to determine jQuery / MVC version?

Tags: asp.net

I try to follow [Creating a Custom Scaffolder for Visual Studio] 
to create a scaffolder for MVC
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx

then I have a question,
How to determine active project environment ? like: jQuery version, MVC version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scaffolding APIs will help you with info on the project but not the type of info you are looking for here. Unfortunately I don't think that there is one set of APIs that you'll need. Instead for each question there may be different solutions.

For example for the question *Which version of jQuery is installed?* There is no definitive way to know. You have the following different ways for jQuery to get added to a project.

1. Through a NuGet package
2. Manually downloaded and installed
3. Through some other means like bower/grunt

The best one to use is likely the NuGet packages. To determine what NuGet packages are installed in a project I think you'll have to manually read `packages.config`. There may be a VS API that returns it but I'm not sure.

For the question *Which version of MVC is being used?* You should be able to determine that by the References in the .csproj file. You can use MSBuild/VS APIs to get to that list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to determine which version of jQuery is installed if it (or its minimized version) is bundled (ASP.NET MVC 4 and later).  Additionally, if you use the {version} feature in bundling, the version can be changed, certainly with NuGet, and (I am guessing) through other mechanisms (including manually), and your code will recognize the change automatically.  This is useful for things like PhantomJS.

So in your App_Start folder in the BundleConfig class, bundle your jQuery:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

This can then be rendered outside of the normal use of bundles, namely the view engine, as an IHtmlString value.  Below is the code.  The value is a full HTML script.  The last two lines convert the value to a string and eliminate the opening and closing script tags so that it can be displayed later in this post easily.

```
IHtmlString jQueryScript = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");

string jQueryVersion = jQueryScript.ToString().Replace("<script ", "").Replace("></script>", "");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jQueryVersion);
```

Here is the text that appears in the "Output" window after a debug run:

src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"

When I first ran this, it produced the version installed with VS 2015 (1.10 something).  I then updated via NuGet and the line successfully detected the newly installed version (2.2).